# Stream Bluetooth over network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth

Due to the global pandemic I started using Zwift on my smart turbo trainer using my Android tablet as the controller running Zwift. The communication between the turbo and tablet runs over Bluetooth. However, the graphics on my tablet are quite bad and I have a full blown gaming rig sitting in another part of my house that would make the experience a lot better in my opinion. Problem is that I can't move my PC near my turbo trainer and I can't move my turbo trainer near my PC.

Is there any possibility to relay the Bluetooth signal over the network to my PC? That way I can just open an RDP connection on my tablet and experience the enhanced graphics. I know this wouldn't be the most clean solution, but it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. WiFi and Bluetooth are not compatible with each other, and I am not aware of any adapters/converters for them. If you can connect an external USB Bluetooth adapter to your PC, you can try with USB extension cable to bring the Bluetooth adapter near your Smart Turbo Trainer.